# Drop down submenu items have different spacing in different browsers

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a css made drop down menu and i have an issue where the first two submenu items don't have spacing between them in chrome
[image: chrome]
 
but they have in mozzilla
[image: mozzilla]

```
    #nav ul li{
     padding-top: 1px;
     float: none;}
```

above css shows where i put that 1px spacing.

Anyone has an idea how can this be fixed ?

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset at all?

Comment: Nope. Until now, I never heared of it :(

Comment: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/